Solve for real $x$: $\sqrt{x^2-4x+3} \ge 2-x$ .

Solve for real $x$: $\, \sqrt{x^2-4x+3} \ge 2-x$ .

First of all $x^2 - 4x + 3 \ge 0 \implies x \in (-\infty, 1]  \cup  [3, \infty)$ .
Clearly the interval $[3, \infty)$ satisfies the above inequality as the LHS gives non negative value whereas RHS gives negative value but I'm not sure about the range $(-\infty, 1]$ since in that case both LHS and RHS are giving non negative values .

For $x\in(-\infty, 1]$ you can square both sides since both sides are $\geq 0$ and so it won't change the sign of the inequality. When you do that you end up with $3>4$ which isn't possible, so there is no solutions for $x\in (-\infty, 1]$.

When $x\leq 1$, one may conclude that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^{2} - 4x + 3} < \sqrt{x^{2} - 4x + 4} = \sqrt{(2 - x)^{2}} = 2 - x
\end{align*}
whence we conclude the solution set is given by $S = [3,+\infty)$.

With $x\le1$ or $x\ge3,$
if $2-x<0\iff x>2, 2-x<0$ but $\sqrt{x^2-4x+3}\ge0\implies x\ge3$ is a solution.
else for $x\le2,2-x\ge0$
$$\sqrt{x^2-4x+3}\ge2-x\iff x^2-4x+3\ge(2-x)^2=x^2=4x+4\iff 3\ge4$$ which is impossible to attain

$x^2-4x+3=(x-1)(x-3),$ which is negative when $1<x<3.$ Otherwise, $$\sqrt{x^2-4x+3}\leq |2-x|$$ by $AM/GM.$ So the only way is when $2-x<0,$ or $x>2$ and $x\notin(1,3).$
So $x\geq3.$
